# Keeping the driver idle for 15 minutes

Tags: java, selenium, appium, appium-ios

I got one scenario where 15 minutes of app (Android and iOS) inactivity has to be recorded and after that it should verify if application has logged out and Sign-In page is displayed. Is there any possible way to write test script for that? I am using Selenium commands with Java.

How is it possible to maintain the appium session for exactly 15 minutes and then continue verifying the test case.

Comment: While not strictly "an answer", for our e2e tests we have an exposed an internal testing server endpoint to 'kill the session'. It has been verified by separate tests that this is the same operation as an idle session timeout (in particular that there is a timeout applied by the server), and such is not covered under the e2e test. Then the Selenium test/harness only has to invoke this "kill session" to be able to *immediately* test how a killed session reacts, which is the more interesting Selenium/e2e test.

Comment: i think you can write testcase for serverside application, where in you will check after 15 min of inactivity the session is invalidated or not. I am not sure if it will be possible to write test case for app.

Comment: right now i am passing the timeout value as parameter and using in for loop as below.  e.g - timeout = 15                                                                                        public void timeOutStatus(Integer timeout) throws Exception
 {

  int value =60000;
  for(int i=0;i<timeout;i++)
  {
   Thread.sleep(value);
  }

 }

Answer (score 1):

You can increase Appium timeout using below command:

```
capabilities.setCapability("newCommandTimeout", 60 * 15);
```

I have never tried this code, please check might be it help you.

More detail check link : http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#appium-server-capabilities

Thanks
Sadik

Answer (score 0):

I have found an workaround for this question by using this functionality provided in Appium Driver.

```
public void startActivity(String appPackage, String appActivity,
            String appWaitPackage, String appWaitActivity)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {}
```

and calling the method as:

```
((AndroidDriver<?>) getDriver()).startActivity(String apppackage name, String appactivityname,String waitforpackage,String waitforactivity);
```